# "404 Error" When Trying to Register a New User in React App - Routing or Port Issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, http-status-code-404

I'm encountering a "404 (Not Found)" error while attempting to register a new user in my React-Express application. I suspect that it might be related to a routing issue or a problem with my Express server configuration. I'm relatively new to React and Express, so the error might be something simple that I'm overlooking.

Here's the relevant code from my application:

Register.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

const Register = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  const navigateTo = useNavigate();

  const createUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user/register", {
      Email: email,
      UserName: userName,
      Password: password,
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("User has been created!");
        navigateTo("/login");

        setEmail("");
        setUserName("");
        setPassword("");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log("Server answered with an error");
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log("Network error");
        } else {
          console.log("Unexpected error:", error.message);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Your JSX code here */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
const userRoutes = require("./controllers/userController.js");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/user', userRoutes); // Updated route path to '/user'

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server online" + port);
});
```

userController.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const db = require("../dataBase/dbConnection");

router.post("/register", async function (req, res) {
  const { Email, UserName, Password } = req.body;

  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(Password, 10);

    const SQL = 'INSERT INTO Users (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    const values = [Email, UserName, hashedPassword];

    await db.query(SQL, values);

    console.log('User inserted successfully!');
    res.send({ message: 'User added!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Register Error:", error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: "Register error" });
  }
});
```

I can add more code here as needed.

Despite reviewing the code and making some adjustments, I'm still encountering a "404 (Not Found)" error when trying to register a user through my React application. I believe the issue may be related to my routing configuration or the way my Express server handles the request.

If anyone could provide insights or solutions to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm eager to learn and overcome this challenge in my journey with React and Express.

Comment: 404 is a ***server*** response status. The "issue" is in the backend where it's not able to find *something* and returns a 404. You'll need to investigate/debug the backend code to see why it's returning a 404.

Comment: I am assuming you have exported `router` from `userController.js`.  Other than that your code seems fine, I have tried and it worked for me. May be you should try adding more debug logs in your `server.js` and `userController.js` and test it using postman.

Comment: also before writing all logic including db operations, you should consider adding get method to router to check if routes are working, that way it will be easier for you to find root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advices ! I will try adding debugging logs and including a GET endpoint to check if the routes are functioning correctly. I truly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check PORT in .env
   2)Try to make request from Postman

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your suggestions. I've checked the PORT in my server configuration, which is set to 5000, and tried making a request from Postman. However, the issue persists.

Notably, my Express server uses port 5000, while my React server runs on port 3000. I've installed nodemon, but I suspect my configuration might be incorrect, which could be contributing to the problem.

I appreciate your assistance and any further insights or recommendations you can provide. I'm eager to resolve this issue and make my application work as expected.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).